# Cannot load pickle file after uploaded and downloading from AWS Glacier

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pickle

Currently I cannot

```
pkl_file = open(item, 'rb')
meta = pickle.load(pkl_file)
print type(meta)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blob-pickles.py", line 16, in <module>
    meta = pickle.load(pkl_file);print type(meta)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\x00'
```

pointing to the `pickle.load()` line

Originally i saved the pickle like this :

```
  output = open(fileName+'.pkl', 'wb')
  pickle.dump(meta, output)
```

where meta was a list with 4 strings

So I tried

```
pickle.loads()
```

And I get EOF error. The files are not blank...

When I wrote the pickles i used `wb` mode and also to read them..

What went wrong or what can i do to retrieve the information within which is just a small list?

`pickle` left a bad taste in my mouth. Next time I'll try [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill). Maybe their code is more kosher.

Comment: what is the full traceback?

Comment: How did you upload the file?

Comment: With a program on windows called FastGlacier. All the other files including pdf and tiff were fine

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Also, please detail how you originally saved the pickle file.

Comment: Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)

Comment: ok i edited the pickle.dump

Comment: Can you binary compare the original file with the upload/download version?

Comment: Can you check the md5sum on AWS? Also have you diffed the original file and the downloaded?